# Can't import Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, xgboost

When I import `tensorflow` it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     40     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 41   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     42   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: /home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-67acea67bc13> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 from functools import partial
      3 from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
      4 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     50 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     51 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 52   raise ImportError(msg)
     53 
     54 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

And many other ML libraries also refuse to load (e.g., `xgboost`). I'm currently on Ubuntu 16.04. I just updated `anaconda` to latest version 4.4 yesterday. How can I get it back to work?

Comment: Are you running on a text editor or on the terminal? This happens when I run my code on sublime.

Comment: @leekwotsin neither. I use Jupyter Notebook actually. It happens in larger part due to anaconda upgrade I guess. But I don't know how to deal with this.